Looking for a Way to Subset Dataset Such That It Only Contains Variables That Start with Certain Variables
I'm trying to write code such that I would subset my dataset so that it only includes variables that start with particular letters. For example:
l_raw_2 = l_raw_1[, names(l_raw_1) %in% c("record_id", names(l_raw_1)[substr(names(l_raw_1), 1, 2) == "ba"])]

In this code, I am subsetting my data set such that the subsetted dataset only includes variables that start with "BA". However, is there a way to subset the data set such that it includes variables starting with "BA" and other series of letters (e.g. "HX", "PE", etc.) all in one string of code? It seems that including an OR-statement results in an error. For example:
l_raw_2 = l_raw_1[, names(l_raw_1) %in% c("record_id", names(l_raw_1)[substr(names(l_raw_1), 1, 2) == "ba" OR "hx" ])]


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

There are a couple of issues in your code. Firstly, the vectorised logical or operator in R is | (not OR). See the Syntax docs.
Let's create a data frame to walk through this:
l_raw_1 <- data.frame(
    record_id = 1, BA1 = 2, HX1 = 3, PE1 = 4, ABA1 = 5, AHX1 = 6
)

base R approach
Base R has a startsWith() function. If you were searching for one pattern, it's simpler to use this than messing around with substr() (and also faster). This is how you would use it to select the "record_id" column and columns starting with "BA":
l_raw_1[
    ,
    names(l_raw_1) == "record_id" |
        startsWith(names(l_raw_1), "BA")
]

You can see that with multiple patterns this is going to get very verbose. It's simpler to use a regular expression here.
If you really want to do this in one line you can:
l_raw_1[, names(l_raw_1) == "record_id" | grepl("^BA|^HX|^PE", names(l_raw_1))]
#   record_id BA1 HX1 PE1
# 1         1   2   3   4

However, I think it's more expressive to write a function to do this. It will also be less code if you are frequently doing this:
subset_by_prefix <- function(dat, exact_names, prefixes) {
    pattern <- paste0("^", prefixes, collapse = "|")
    dat[, names(dat) %in% exact_names | grepl(pattern, names(dat))]
}

Then you can simply do:
subset_by_prefix(l_raw_1, exact_names = "record_id", prefixes = c("BA", "HX", "PE"))
#   record_id BA1 HX1 PE1
# 1         1   2   3   4

dplyr approach
Alternatively, this is quite straightforward using dplyr::starts_with():
library(dplyr)

l_raw_1 |>
    select(
        record_id,
        starts_with(c("BA", "HX", "PE"))
    )

#   record_id BA1 HX1 PE1
# 1         1   2   3   4

